# Materialize search, autocomplete. How to change site depending on the option selected?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I recently got interested in Materialize and tried doing a project with it but I'm struggling with changing site using autocomplete.

I'm doing a travel agency site and for example if someone selects Bahama I want it to go to bahamaoffer.html and if someone selects Bali to balioffer.html.

I saw in documentation that you can use onAutocomplete option that fires a function whenever someone uses autocomplete but I just can't figure out what parameter should I pass there.

I have a general idea what I want to do but I need a inner text from what was selected and I don't know how to pass that object to a function that runs with onAutocomplete.

I tried reading the source code and figure that out myself but I'm a beginner and it's just too complex for me right now.

I'll post some code for you to get better insight.

Right now all it does is whatever user selects it changes the site to 'balioferta.html'.

```js
  const autoComplete = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
  M.Autocomplete.init(autoComplete, {
    data: {
      "Bali": null,
      "Bahama": null,
      "Wyspy Kanaryjskie": null,
      "Ibiza": null,
      "Madagaskar": null,
      "Australia": null,
      "Polska": null,
      "Tybet": null
    },
    limit: 5,
    minLength: 2,
    onAutocomplete: () => {
      window.location = 'balioferta.html';
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it myself and it was really simple. All I had to do is to put one argument.

For future  reference if anyone encounters this problem.

```js
const autoComplete = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
  M.Autocomplete.init(autoComplete, {
    data: {
      "Bali": null,
      "Bahama": null,
      "Wyspy Kanaryjskie": null,
      "Ibiza": null,
      "Madagaskar": null,
      "Australia": null,
      "Polska": null,
      "Tybet": null
    },
    limit: 5,
    minLength: 2,
    onAutocomplete: (res) => {
      let siteHTML = res.toLowerCase() + 'offer.html';
      window.location = siteHTML;
    }
  });
```